# Axis with either dynamic tickFormats or multipe axis with different timeScales

Tags: d3.js, axis

I'd like to **either**:

dynamically adjust the tickFormat of an D3 timeaxis depending on current zoom, like first showing years -> zoom in -> show months -> zoom in -> show days and so on up to seconds.

I've tried a bit. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy72n/).

```
 var w = 700,
     h = 50,
     xY = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]),

     xAxisY = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(xY)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(10)
         .tickSize(10, 1)

     var svgY = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h)
     .append("svg:g");

 svgY.append("svg:g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 10 + ")");

 svgY.append("svg:rect")
     .attr("class", "pane")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h)
     .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));

 xY.domain([new Date(2000, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 0)]);
 xY.ticks(d3.time.minute, 1);

 draw();

 function draw() {
     console.log("drawing");
     svgY.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxisY);
 }

 function zoom() {
     console.log("zooming");
     d3.event.transform(xY); // TODO d3.behavior.zoom should support extents
     draw();
 }
```

It would be nice if the label format could be adjusted. If I zoom into minutely interval, th complete time shold be displayed ( 12:01 ) instead of sth like 12:00..............10......20......30....

**or ( preferred, if possible ) :**

add multiple x-axis with different formats below each other. In this case, the labels should disappear on overlap, eg:

-------2012--------------------------------------------------------------2013-----------------
--12----01----02----03----04----05----06----07----08----09----10----11----12----01----02------

Below the monthly axis there should appear a daily and so on. If I zoom into an detailled interval, the overlapping labels should disappear.

For this case I tried playing around with the above fiddle, simply adding futher axis / svgs but they react independently, eg: I have a yearly axis and a monthly axis. Zooming on the first also zooms the second and vice versa, but when I first change from first to second, both axis do a "jump". I think the second one moves back to its initial state on first moving.

Any ways to accomblish this?

In both cases, I'm surprised why the tick-lines have gone away?
In many examples the axis look like:

---

|2012       |2011       |2010

but the vertical lines are gone in the fiddled example!?

Comment: For the first option, you have to change the tick format when you're zooming.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. Is there a way to check current minimum and maximum which is displayed on screen?

Comment: You can attach the scales to the zoom behaviour so that they are modified automatically.